# Help! Where am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

> Help! Can you tell me where am I?
>   If you don't come soon, it'll be a bye-bye!
>   It's hard to breathe, it's hard to walk
>   And I met some citizens who can talk!
>
> First, **Steven Spielberg**, who seems a bit yellow
>   He is quite attractive and merry
>   Also, **Paul Scholes**, who lives a bit low
>   He looks pointless and lazy
>
> The rich **Edward Kennedy** and his child, **Phil Kessel**
>   Also I met a karate master, **Simon Cowell**
>   And the grumpy old **Savielly Tartakower**, who's quite musical
>   With the famous **Sir Ferguson**, his big rival
>
> Also **Sarah Palin**, the most evil
>   Yet she never get his job done still
>   Then **Pablo Picasso** with his boat
>   It seems that he drives a lot!
>
> Oops, I almost forgot something very important
>   Googling the names above is forbidden
>   Because they are not the actual names, really
>   But can you just tell me what is this city?

P.S. :

> Sorry if one of the people mentioned gets insulted; but I met someone like you down here!

Comment: Sounds like Manchester to me(because Paul Scholes and Sir Alex Ferguson). I am sure there is something else that will confirm what the answer is, though

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> You are in Bikini Bottom

Why did I think so?

For the first stanza, you hinted not being able to walk or breathe.

> Underwater

Also, from the way you word "Citizens can talk!"

> It makes it sound like they aren't suppose to talk.

In order of the initial letters of bolded names:

> **S**pongebob **S**quarepants - *is yellow*
>  **P**atrick **S**tar - *lives under a rock (lives a bit low)*
>  **E**ugene **K**rabs *and his daughter* **P**earl **K**rabs
>  **S**andy **C**heeks - *literally a Karate Master*
>  **S**quidward **T**entacles - *known to be very grumpy and plays the clarinet*
>  **S**quilliam **F**ancyson - *in one or more episode is known to be his rival (the squid with a unibrow)*
>  **S**heldon **P**lankton - *the villain in Spongebob Squarepants*
>  **P**oppy **P**uffs - *Spongebob's driving teacher*

Comment: HA!  The initials are the same as the characters...  Nice.  Would never have gotten that. +1

Comment: I knew this was easy! Would accept it later once more people view (and hopefully upvote) the riddle! NB: #KembalikanSpongebob #GlobalTV

Comment: Yeah I got a bit lucky correlating yellow and the initials SS. Btw, really love how you make your puzzles rhyme and sensible. Always looking forward to your next puzzle! @WilliamNathanael

Comment: @WilliamNathanael Is there a good reason not to immediately accept an answer that's totally correct? Just from your comment it seems like you're trying to inflate the question (which might be fine - I'm just curious)

Comment: @Samthere It's fairly common practice to not immediately accept answers as it discourages other users from reading/viewing the puzzle.